# Usestate not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-state

Pretty new to React Hooks and I'm running into a problem with a third party api.  I'm getting the data but it's the useState hook isn't updating my state value.  I'm pretty sure this is the problem bc I'm getting an error that items.map isn't a function.  It does this bc there's nothing in items???  Anyone know how to deal with this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const FeaturedWorks = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const fetchRandomData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios(
        `https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/en/collection?key=XXXXXXX`
      );
     setItems(res.data.artObjects);
      console.log(res);
      console.log(items);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRandomData();
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="featured-container">
      {items.map((item, idX) => (
        <h5 key={idX}>{item.title}</h5>
      ))}
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedWorks;
```

Here's a screenshot of my response:
[image]

Comment: are you sure the data returned from your API call is valid and an array?

Comment: you also need to add your api response sample in your question. There is something wrong with it, everything else seems good, and you need to change `{item}` to something else like `test` for testing purpose in your `h5` .

Comment: Ok, I added my api response if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing `[]` as the initial state for `items`, it's already an (empty) array on the first render. If `items` is not updated, `items.map` will still work, since `.map` still exists for an empty array.

So, my guess is that your `setItems` is indeed updating the state with the result from your query, but `res.data` is not an array. If `res.data` is and object like `{ values: ['foo', 'bar'] }`, instead of an array like `['foo', 'bar']`, then `items` will be set to this object and `items.map()` will in fact throw an error since the object must be an array for the `.map` function to be defined.

Does you `console.log(res.data);` really logs an array, or does it log something different?

Comment: So you're right it is an object.  Within res.data there is artObjects, which looks like an array with objects.

Comment: Right. So if you use `setItems` with `res.data.artObjects` instead of just `res.data`, your `items.map` should work again, correct?

However, if `artObjects` is an array of objects, you may encounter another problem. The `item` passed as children to your `<h5>`  tags will be said objects, which may trigger the error `Objects are not valid as a React child`. Maybe there is some primitive property in these objects that you intend to use as the content for the `<h5>` instead of the whole object? E.g., if there is an `id` property, you could make it work with `<h5 key={idX}>{item.id}</h5>`

Comment: It's still just coming back as an empty array.   If I console.log res, it shows all the data, but if I log 'items', its an empty array.  However if I change anything in the file it will log the right data.  I think it's something in the setItems function.

Comment: So I maybe answering my own question here, but I passed {items} to another component via props, and now it's working.  Do you know why this would be?